# Pentaho: Barchart Color as per defined parameters

Tags: pentaho

I have a single bar chart for Operating Income vs Goal. I have a requirement to change the bar color depending on the specified range. 
Here is the range:

```
Green = 100% and higher
Yellow = 85% - 99%
Red = 0% - 84%
```

I am not that familiar with javascript in PDE. I tried researching but did not find any concrete answers. Can anyone please help me?[image]

Comment: Which tool you are using? Pentaho report designer or pentaho business analytics?

Comment: @WorkingHard..I am using Pentaho Business Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using conditional formatting code into pre-execution property of a bar chart.

```
function changeBars(){
var cccOptions = this.chartDefinition;

// For changing extension points, a little more work is required:
var eps = Dashboards.propertiesArrayToObject(cccOptions.extensionPoints);

// add extension points:
eps.bar_fillStyle = function getColor(){
var val = this.scene.vars.value.value;

if(val > 0 && val <= 5000){
return 'red';
}
else if(val > 5000 && val <= 50000){
return 'green';
}
else{
return 'black';
}
};

// Serialize back eps into cccOptions
cccOptions.extensionPoints = Dashboards.objectToPropertiesArray(eps);
}
```

Find below link for more details. [http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.com/2014/10/conditional-coloring-of-bars-in-pentaho.html](http://you%20can%20achieve%20this%20by%20using%20conditional%20formatting%20code%20into%20pre-execution%20property%20of%20a%20bar%20chart.)